# Why my code give empty plots? AND When I increase the number of mx , mt my code is running for a long time

Tags: differential-equations, regular-expressions, continued-fractions, inverse-function

In my code, two graphs are not displayed. what is the problem?Also when I increase the number of mx and mt, the code enters the running for a long time.
The regularization problem is described as 
$D^{\alpha}w_t(x,t)=w_{xx}(x,t) , 0<x<s(t),0<t<T$ , (1)

$w(x,0)=J_{\delta_{1}}\phi^\epsilon(x),0\leq x\leq s(0),$(2)
$w(s(t),t)=0,0\leq t\leq T,$(3)

$w_(s(t),t)=-J_{\delta_2}g^\epsilon_2(t),0\leq t\leq T,$(4)

where $J_\delta(.)$shows the mollification function with respect to the radius of mollification,$\delta$.

```
(*Inverse fractional Stefan problem by mollification and Marching \
scheme*)
ClearAll[a, exact, g, g1, g2, f, epsilon, deltax];
a = .5;(*a= alpha*)
T = 1;
exact[x_, t_] = .5*Sqrt[Pi]*x^2 + 2 Sqrt[t];(*   u(x,t)  *)
phi[x_] = exact[x, 0];(*   u(x,0)=\[Phi]  *)
g[t_] = Sqrt[t^2 + 2];(*   s(t)  *)
g1[t_] = exact[g[t], t];(*   u(s(t),t)=Subscript[g, 1](t)  *)
g2[t_] = D[exact[x, t], x] /. 
  x -> g[t];(*   Subscript[u, x](s(t),t)=Subscript[g, 2](t)  *)
f[s_, z_] = Sqrt[Pi]*.5 - D[exact[s, z], {s, 2}];
epsilon = 0.01*Sqrt[3];
 deltax = 0.05; deltat = 0.07;
 Mx = 20;
Mt = 30;
 h = N[g[0]/Mx];
k = N[T/Mt];
rx = Floor[(3*deltax)/h];
 rt = Floor[(3*deltat)/k];
Array[tim, Mt + 3, -1];
Array[\[Theta], Mt + 1, 0];
Array[M, Mt + 1, 0];
Do[tim[j] = j*k, {j, -1, Mt + 1}];
Do[M[n] = Floor[g[tim[n]]/h]; \[Theta][n] = g[tim[n]]/h - M[n], {n, 0,
   Mt}];
Do[points[i] = Array[meshpoint, {1, M[i] + 1}, {i, 0}], {i, 0, Mt}];
Do[points1[i] = Array[meshpoint1, {1, M[i] + 1}, {i, 0}], {i, 0, Mt}];
Do[meshpoint[i, j] = j*h, {i, 0, Mt}, {j, 0, M[i]}]
Array[points, Mt + 1, 0];
MatrixForm[Array[points, Mt + 1, 0]];
Do[meshpoint1[i, j] = {j*h, tim[i]}, {i, 0, Mt}, {j, 0, M[i]}];
MatrixForm[Array[points1, Mt + 1, 0]];
ListPlot[Flatten[Array[points1, Mt + 1, 0], 2]];
Ap = 1/NIntegrate[Exp[-t^2], {t, -3, 3}];
ro[t_, delta_] = Ap/delta*Exp[-t^2/delta^2];
Do[s2[i] = i*h, {i, -rx, Mx + rx}];
Do[s2t[i] = i*k, {i, -rt, Mt + rt}];
a12 = epsilon*RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {Mx + 1}];
Do[noisephi[i] = phi[meshpoint[0, i]] + a12[[i + 1]], {i, 0, Mx}];
RO[x_] = g[0]/(Mx + 1) Sum[
    ro[x - s2[i], deltax]*noisephi[i], {i, 0, Mx}];
c1 = NIntegrate[(phi[x] - (RO[x]))*
     Integrate[ro[x - z, deltax], {z, -3*deltax, 0}], {x, 0, 
     3*deltax}]/
   NIntegrate[
    Integrate[ro[x - z, deltax], {z, -3*deltax, 0}]^2, {x, 0, 
     3*deltax}];
c2 = NIntegrate[(phi[x] - (RO[x]))*
     Integrate[ro[x - z, deltax], {z, g[0], g[0] + 3*deltax}], {x, 
     g[0] - 3*deltax, g[0]}]/
   NIntegrate[
    Integrate[ro[x - z, deltax], {z, g[0], g[0] + 3*deltax}]^2, {x, 
     g[0] - 3*deltax, g[0]}];
If[rx > 0, 
  RO1[x_] = (
    3*deltax)/(rx + 1) Sum[ro[x - s2[i], deltax]*c1, {i, -rx, -1}], 
  RO1[x_] = 0];
RO3[x_] = (
   3*deltax)/(rx + 1) Sum[
    ro[x - s2[i], deltax]*c2, {i, Mx + 1, Mx + rx}];
jphi2[x_] = 
  Piecewise[{{RO1[x] + RO[x], 0 <= x < 3*deltax}, {RO[x], 
     3*deltax <= x < g[0] - 3*deltax}, {RO3[x] + 
      RO[x], (g[0] - 3*deltax) <= x <= g[0]}}];
(1/(Mx + 1)
    Sum[(exact[meshpoint[0, j], 0] - jphi2[meshpoint[0, j]])^2, {j, 0,
      Mx}])^(1/2)
o1 = Plot[phi[x], {x, 0, g[0]}]
o2 = Plot[jphi2[x], {x, 0, g[0]}]
Show[o1, o2]
(**********************jg2*****************************************)
Do[
  noiseg2[n] = g2[n*k] + a12[[n + 1]], {n, 0, Mt}];
ROg2[t_] = 
  1/(Mt + 1) Sum[ro[t - s2t[i], deltat]*noiseg2[i], {i, 0, Mt}];
c1g2 = NIntegrate[(g2[t] - (ROg2[t]))*
     Integrate[ro[t - z, deltat], {z, -3*deltat, 0}], {t, 0, 
     3*deltat}]/
   NIntegrate[
    Integrate[ro[t - z, deltat], {z, -3*deltat, 0}]^2, {t, 0, 
     3*deltat}];
c2g2 = NIntegrate[(g2[t] - (ROg2[t]))*
     Integrate[ro[t - z, deltat], {z, 1, 1 + 3*deltat}], {t, 
     1 - 3*deltat, 1}]/
   NIntegrate[
    Integrate[ro[t - z, deltat], {z, 1, 1 + 3*deltat}]^2, {t, 
     1 - 3*deltat, 1}];
If[rt > 0, 
  RO1g2[t_] = (
    3*deltat)/(rt + 1) Sum[ro[t - s2t[i], deltat]*c1g2, {i, -rt, 0}], 
  RO1[t_] = 0];
RO3g2[t_] = (
   3*deltat)/(rt + 1) Sum[
    ro[t - s2t[i], deltat]*c2g2, {i, Mt, Mt + rt}];
RO4g2[t_] = (
   1 + 3*deltat)/(Mt + rt + 1) Sum[
    ro[t - s2t[i], deltat]*noiseg2[i], {i, 0, Mt}];
jg2[t_] = 
  Piecewise[{{RO1g2[t] + ROg2[t], 0 <= t < 3*deltat}, {ROg2[t], 
     3*deltat <= t < 1 - 3*deltat}, {RO3g2[t] + 
      RO4g2[t], (1 - 3*deltat) <= t <= 1}}];
o1g = Plot[g2[t], {t, 0, 1}]
o2g = Plot[jg2[t], {t, 0, 1}]
Show[o1g, o2g]
(1/(Mt + 1) Sum[((g2[n*k]) - jg2[n*k])^2, {n, 0, Mt}])^(1/2)

gt[x_] = If[x >= g[0], (3 - (2 - x)^2)/2, 0];
Array[num, M[Mt] + 1, 0];
Do[num[i] = 
   If[gt[i*h] < 0, 0, 
    If[gt[i*h]/k == Floor[gt[i*h]/k], gt[i*h]/k, 
     Floor[gt[i*h]/k] + 1]], {i, 0, M[Mt]}];
Array[num, M[Mt] + 1, 0]
(*************************************************************************************************)


Do[
  u1[j, 0] = jphi2[j*h], {j, 0, M[0]}];
Q1[0, 0] = (jphi2[h] - jphi2[0])/(h);
Q1[M[0], 0] = (jphi2[(M[0])*h] - jphi2[(M[0] - 1)*h])/(h);
Do[
  Q1[j, 0] = (jphi2[(j + 1)*h] - jphi2[(j - 1)*h])/(2*h), {j, 1, 
   M[0] - 1}];
Do[
  Q1[M[n] + \[Theta][n], n] = jg2[n*k];
  u1[M[n] + \[Theta][n], n] = 0;
  w1[M[n] + \[Theta][n], n] = -1
  , {n, 0, Mt}];
Do[
  u1[M[n], 
    n] = -\[Theta][n]*h*Q1[M[n] + \[Theta][n], n] + 
     u1[M[n] + \[Theta][n], n] // N;
  Q1[M[n], n] = -\[Theta][n]*h*(-f[(M[n] + \[Theta][n])*h, n*k]) + 
    Q1[M[n] + \[Theta][n], n];
  w1[M[n], n] = w1[M[n] + \[Theta][n], n]
  , {n, 1, Mt}];
Do[Do[ww[i_] := 
    N[1/Gamma[1 - a]*1/(
      1 - a)*(((2*i + 1)*deltat/2)^(1 - a) - ((2*i - 1)*deltat/2)^(1 -
            a))], {i, 1, j - 1}], {j, 1, Mt}];
Do[wwj[jj_] := 
   N[1/Gamma[1 - a]*1/(
     1 - a)*(jj*deltat - ((jj - .5)*deltat)^(1 - a))], {jj, 1, Mt}];
ww[1] = N[1/Gamma[1 - a]*1/(1 - a)*(deltat/2)^(1 - a)];

Do[rq3[M[Mt] - j] = Floor[((3*(1 - num[M[Mt] - j]*k))/6)/k];
  u1[M[Mt] - j - 1, n] = u1[M[Mt] - j, n] - h*Q1[M[Mt] - j, n] // N;
  Q1[M[Mt] - j - 1, 
    n] = -h*(w1[M[Mt] - j, n] - f[(M[Mt] - j)*h, n*k]) + 
    Q1[M[Mt] - j, n];
  jQ1[M[Mt] - j, t_] = 
   If[num[-j + M[Mt]] == Mt, 
    0, (1 - num[M[Mt] - j]*k - 
      6*((1 - num[M[Mt] - j]*k)/6))/(Mt - num[M[Mt] - j] + 1 - 
       2*rq3[M[Mt] - j]) Sum[
      ro[t - s1[d], (1 - num[M[Mt] - j]*k)/6]*Q1[M[Mt] - j, d], {d, 
       num[M[Mt] - j] + rq3[M[Mt] - j], Mt - rq3[M[Mt] - j]}]];
  
  df[M[Mt] - j, i_] := 
   N[(jQ1[M[Mt] - j, tim[i + 1]] - jQ1[M[Mt] - j, tim[i]])/
    deltat];(*forward difference*)
  db[M[Mt] - j, i_] := 
   N[(jQ1[M[Mt] - j, tim[i]] - jQ1[M[Mt] - j, tim[i - 1]])/
    deltat];(*backward difference*)
  d0[M[Mt] - j, i_] := 
   N[(jQ1[M[Mt] - j, tim[i + 1]] - jQ1[M[Mt] - j, tim[i - 1]])/(
    2*deltat)];(*central difference*)
  da[M[Mt] - j, 1] = 
   df[M[Mt] - j, 1]*ww[1]    ;                            (*   
  Subscript[(D^\[Alpha]G^\[Epsilon]), \[Delta]](Subscript[t, 1]) *)
  da[M[Mt] - j, 2] = 
   df[M[Mt] - j, 1]*ww[1] + df[M[Mt] - j, 2]*wwj[2]; (*   
  Subscript[(D^\[Alpha]G^\[Epsilon]), \[Delta]](Subscript[t, 2]) *)
  Do[da[M[Mt] - j, k] = 
    df[M[Mt] - j, 1]*ww[1] + df[M[Mt] - j, k]*wwj[k] + 
     Sum[d0[M[Mt] - j, i]*ww[k - i + 1], {i, 2, k - 1}], {k, 3, 
    n}];(*   Subscript[(D^\[Alpha]G^\[Epsilon]), \[Delta]](Subscript[
  t, j]) *)
  
  w1[M[Mt] - j - 1, n] = w1[M[Mt] - j, n] - h*da[M[Mt] - j, n]
  , {j, 0, M[Mt] - M[0] - 1}, {n, num[-j + M[Mt]], Mt}];
Do[
  rq = Floor[3*.16666/k];
  u1[M[Mt] - j - 1, n] = u1[M[Mt] - j, n] - h*Q1[M[Mt] - j, n] // N;
  Q1[M[Mt] - j - 1, 
    n] = -h*(w1[M[Mt] - j, n] - f[(M[Mt] - j)*h, n*k]) + 
    Q1[M[Mt] - j, n];
  jQ1[M[Mt] - j, t_] = 
   If[num[-j + M[Mt]] == Mt, 
    0, (1 - 6*.16666)/(Mt - 2*rq + 1) Sum[
      ro[t - s1[d], .16]*Q1[M[Mt] - j, d], {d, rq, 
       Mt - rq}]];(*Runing*)
  w1[M[Mt] - j - 1, n] = w1[M[Mt] - j, n] - h*da[M[Mt] - j, n + 1]
  , {j, M[Mt] - M[0], M[Mt] - 1}, {n, 0, Mt}];
fi = Table[{tim[i], u1[0, i]}, {i, 0, Mt}];
fi1 = ListLinePlot[fi, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}, Frame -> True]
fi2 = Plot[exact[0, t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True]
Show[fi1, fi2, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Blue, Dotted]]
ss3 = Table[{tim[n], Abs[u1[0, n] - exact[0, n*k]]}, {n, 0, Mt}];
gg5 = ListPlot[ss3, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Blue, Dotted]]
```

Comment: Way, way too complicated. Please try to break it down into something  comprehensible. Try **each** function separately, see that it does what you expect. If you can isolate a *Mathematica* primitive that isn't doing what you need, we can help. The chances of anything this complicated working the first time are negligible.

Comment: What kind of fractional derivative have been used in your code?

Comment: A lot of pointless `Array` calls in here which have no side effects - i.e you're not setting any variables. Also this: `ro[t_, delta_] = Ap/delta*Exp[-t^2/delta^2];` should be `:=` instead and you've got a `ListPlot` with a semicolon after it, suppressing the output.

Comment: @AlexTrounev With numerically approximate that was described by murio in Source terms identiﬁcation for time fractional diﬀusion equation.

Comment: @JohnDoty Can you explain more?

Comment: One thing you could do is for every line that sets a value with an `=` sign, inspect the value to see if it's sensible.